# Remove Symfony CMF content type options from Sonata Admin Menu

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-cmf

Currently I have a dashboard and menu in the Sonata Admin backend which is a combination of my own entities and those which came with Symfony CMF. Ideally I would like to remove the Symfony CMF group as it's not currently used on the site and may lead my client down the wrong path when they use the system.

However I'm struggling to workout out where in the config I have to make this change.

My menu currently looks like this:

```
- Users (group)
- Products (group)
- Knowledge Base (group)
- RMA Tickets (group)
- Support Tickets (group)
- Symfony CMF (group)
    - Static Content
    - Pages
    - Simple Block
    ...
```

I want to remove the whole Symfony CMF group from the menu.

Comment: If I remember correctly by default the SonataAdminBundle doesn't display anything by default. What configuration do you use?

Comment: If that's the case I've probably enabled it whilst following through the installation steps: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/tutorial/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need sonata admin for the cmf parts of the system at all, your easiest solution is to disable them. The easiest to do that is

```
# app/config/config.yml
cmf_core:
    persistence:
        phpcr:
            use_sonata_admin: false
```

By default, the admins are enabled automatically if sonata is available. If you do not have any PHPCR documents to admin, you might also remove `sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle` from composer.json.

In case you do need some of the CMF admin functionalities, you can also specifically control what is on the dashboard. See https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/dashboard.html

And finally, you could use [Sonata Security](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#roles-and-access-control-lists) to control who sees what admins, if some people need to be able to edit pages through sonata, but others don't.

Comment: `Unrecognized option "use_sonata_admin" under "cmf_core"` I also tried putting it under `cmf_core.persistance.phpcr` like it shows here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/routing/configuration.html#use-sonata-admin No luck though.

Comment: ups, indeed i was missing the persistence.phpcr part. i edited my reply to reflect the correct information. what you linked is the cmf_routing configuration. did you put this in cmf_core or cmf_routing? and do you use a new enough version of the CMF? easiest is you check the Configuration.php class of the vendor/symfony-cmf/core-bundle to see if use_sonata_admin is there or not. if its there but does not work, please open a bug issue on github.